# Loading new Storyboard and UIButton inactive

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added a new `UIViewController` to get a log in issue fixed and now the button in the `NavigationBar` on the next scene are inactive. Here is the code I used to load the new StoryBoard:

```
-(void)newSotrybooard{
    UIStoryboard *settingsStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LogedIn" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initialSettingsVC = [settingsStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    initialSettingsVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:initialSettingsVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

I added the new storyboard after I couldn't get the `NavigationBar` to show up and push without and error on the main storyboard. This is the only code that has changed. The Navigation Controller does not have a class associated with it and neither does the TableView to follow. I can also not scroll the Table view. Thank you for your help!

Update:

I updated the code above and

The error I receive is:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x109fa0ce0> on <PrivateViewController: 0x109f6ef80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided, I surmise that the following could be helpful -

1. Yes, you have used `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.
   But, remember it instantiates and returns the view controller with
   the *specified identifier*. You're missing that.
2. Provide the same name to your new Storyboard in your code and
   File Inspector (like you named it *LogedIn* above) and it
   should be set in the Main Interface (Target >> General >> Main
   Interface).
3. See `rootViewController`? The `rootViewController`
   for the window needs to be assigned (either via Storyboard or
   programmatically). Please check. I have added a `UINavigationController` in my example below -

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:nil];

    ViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardName"];

    vc.title = @"Is this title visible?";

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;

    return YES;
}
```

For the ViewController.m

```
 -(void) goToSettings {

        UIStoryboard *settingsStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SettingsStoryboard" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *initialSettingsVC = [settingsStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

        initialSettingsVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

        [self presentViewController:initialSettingsVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: I am using two different storyboards and this is the second storyboard. I want the application to launch from the first storyboard, as it contains a log-in and passcode feature.

Comment: I also should specify that it is the whole view not responding and it happens regardless if it is a navigation controller or not.

Comment: Okay, now its a different ball of game. You can easily jump from one storyboard to the other (no issues?) - and you can 'embed in' a new navigation controller to the second storyboard. Doable?

Comment: Yes, I can jump no problem. When I launch the second storyboard as my main one it works. It is just jumping from the first to second it was giving me trouble.

Comment: Is the question answered now?